# Stable convergence implies convergence of second moments?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X,X_1,X_2,...$ be real valued r.v. s.t. $\mathbb{E}[Uf(X_n)] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[Uf(X)]$ for all bounded r.v. U and $f \in C_b(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ and let $\sup_n\mathbb{E}[(X_n)^p]<\infty$ for all $p   \geq 1$.
Is it true that

$$\mathbb{E}[(X_n)^2] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[X^2]$$

holds? I think the paper I am reading uses this, but I don't know why this should hold. I would be grateful for hints or a solution.

Comment: Let $U \equiv 1$, and $f_m: x \mapsto \min\left(x^2, m\right)$. By stable convergence $$\mathbb{E}\left[\min\left(\left(X_n\right)^2, m\right)\right] \to \mathbb{E}\left[\min\left(\left(X\right)^2, m\right)\right],$$ then you can conclude by monotone convergence.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I don't see why this works. This proof would also show that $X_n \rightarrow X$ weakly implies $\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ for continuous and not bounded $f$, which is not true in general. Or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that taking $U=1$ gives that $X_n \to X$ in distribution. Using Skorokhod's representation theorem, we can assume that there is almost sure convergence.

Now since $X_n$ is bounded in every $L^p$, $X_n^2$ is uniformly integrable. Thus [Vitali's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem#Finite_measure_case) gives the convergence $X_n \to X$ in $L^2$.

Comment: Great, thank you!